# Issue with HTTPS but not with HTTP in VBA (from XML)

Tags: xml, excel, https, vba

I am using VBA to parse some XML files and use their informations to create charts in Excel.
But I have an issue when the XML file has an URL that begins with HTTPS. The error that I recieve is:

```
Run-time error '91' Object variable or With block variable not set"
```

Here is the code that I use to be sure of the issue with HTTPS and not with HTTP:

```
Function GetStr() As String
    Set XmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    XmlDoc.async = False
    XmlDoc.Load ("https://........")
    GetStr = XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/investigations/header/c0/name").Text
End Function

Sub Test()
    Debug.Print GetStr
End Sub
```

This is the line with `GetStr = XmlDoc1...` that causes the issue (for Excel).

When I replace the URL by an HTTP URL, it works well.

Anyone knows what is wrong or has an idea, even he is not sure?